# Make dropdown menu from existing css menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

```css
ul li ul.dropdown{
 min-width: 125px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block;
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
 display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 


 <ul>
 <li><a href = 'index.html'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'media.html'>Media Design</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'innovatie.html'>Innovatieroutes</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'info.html'>Informatie</a></li>
         <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Open dagen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beroepen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Studie</a></li>
   </ul>
 <li><a href = 'contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make a CSS menu with a dropdown, but somehow I am not able to let to menu drop down when I hover the mouse over the tab "Informatie", the sub menus will just display after "Informatie". Maybe some of you guys are able to help me with my menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code

```css
ul li ul.dropdown{
 min-width: 125px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
}
ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block;
}
ul li ul.dropdown li{
 display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 


 <ul>
 <li><a href = 'index.html'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'media.html'>Media Design</a></li>
 <li><a href = 'innovatie.html'>Innovatieroutes</a>
 <li><a href = 'info.html'>Informatie</a>
         <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Open dagen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beroepen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Studie</a></li>
   </ul>
     </li>
 <li><a href = 'contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your mistake was, you wrote the `ul` outside `li`'s closing tag `</li>`. You've to put `ul`'s code right after ending of `a` tag's closing tag `</a>`

Comment: Hi Xahed, somehow when I hover over the tab information, my dropdown won't show up.

Comment: I see its working fine on my answer. If you hover on Information, you see the submenu

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your answer solve it?

Comment: added explanation at the end of answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `ul` inside the `li`.